# MySQL Count of Grouped data joined across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

As a SQL novice just trying to piece things together, I feel there is a more elegant solution to this that I cannot seem to come up with. I've found many examples that seem similar but not exact, and despite that, my query always ends up a mess and doesn't work out. The structure I am dealing with is three tables as outlined in the following with brief examples. A users table with unique id's and various chapter numbers and a member_status of either "SN", "SC', or "GS". A chapters table with unique id's and various province id's. My third table that would be referenced would be my provinces table with the only contributing factor being a list of unique province id's. My user table is an extremely large data set and I am concerned about any use of subqueries or other issues that may affect speed. Some promising examples use Distinct with the Count, but I can't get it organized correctly if so.

My ultimate goal is also exampled below but is to get a Count of all members with a status IN ("SC","SN") who are in chapters that are in a specific province. I know that I have to have my table_users.chapter JOINED to table_chapters.id. I *think* I also need to have my table_chapters.province_id JOINED to table_provinces.id. Between the potential Count and Group By aspects, I just get lost and any help would be appreciated. I'd be happy to supply additional information if requested.

I've taken a shot at loading my data in SQLFiddle if it helps.

[Check here for SQLFiddle schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4da100)

**Data Schema**

table_users

```
id | chapter | member_status
---------------------
1  |   101   |   GS
2  |   101   |   SN
3  |   101   |   SC
4  |   102   |   SN
5  |   102   |   GS
6  |   103   |   SC
7  |   103   |   SC
8  |   104   |   SN
9  |   104   |   SN
10 |   104   |   SC
11 |   105   |   GS
12 |   105   |   SC
```

table_chapters

```
id   | province_id
-------------------
101  |     1
102  |     2
103  |     2
104  |     1
105  |     3
```

table_provinces

```
table_provinces just with sequential list by id
```

**Desired Output**

```
Province id | Count of Members
------------------------------
      1     |       5
      2     |       3
      3     |       1
```

*Notice the output ignores status of "GS"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the count of all user record matched with chapter in other table.

Try this:

```
select c.province_id,count(u.member_status) as member_count from users u 
inner join chapters c on u.chapter=c.id
where u.member_status in ('SC','SN')
group by c.province_id
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4da100/5

Comment: Perfect right off the bat. Much appreciated, this also gave me some good insights that will help in the future.